# How to annotate a hash in google closure?

Tags: javascript, annotations, google-closure

The [google closure reference](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html#types) demonstrates how to annotate a record:

```
{{myNum: number, myObject}} 
An anonymous type with both a property named myNum that has a value of type number and a property named myObject that has a value of any type.
```

I have a hash of arbitrary strings to numbers. It's not clear how I indicate this since in the example the left hand side is a specific property name both times. How should I annotate my hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/** @type {Object.<number>} */
```

or

```
/** @type {Object.<string, number>} */
```